# Windows 8.1 app start menu error

Tags: windows-8.1

If I try to install some applications on Windows 8.1 I get an error about start menu folder permissions. I have tried running as administrator and it doesn't do anything.

An example from dotPeek: "The installer has insufficient privileges to access this directory: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\JetBrains dotPeek version 1.1."

I can't find any information online and windows compatibility troubleshooter doesn't fix it either.

The issue is with msi files. I have even tried running from an admin cmd.

Comment: I'm interested to see who the owner of the `Start Menu` and `Programs` folder is.

Comment: It was set to system. I took ownership and it fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it, but I think system is the correct owner. +1

Comment: Interesting, so is it possible that there is just an issue with msi permissions?